# WebSocket connection closes after calling child process

Tags: javascript, websocket, spawn

Here's the setup: I create simple WebSocket Server using the ws library. I then attach a listener for when the client sends me the URL of a PDF to transform. I download it locally then I call another command to transform it:

```
const download = require("download");
wss.on("connection", ws => {
  ws.onmessage = async msg => {
    await download(msg.data, destination, {
      filename: fileName
    });

    transformPDF(ws, msg.data);
  };

  // ...
});
```

After that, the transformPDF function calls the spawn command to execute a command line binary. I parse the percentage done from the stdout and then try to emit it to the client. But even before this, the connection has been closed and I'm not sure why:

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");
const transformPDF = (ws, url) => {
  // ...
  const child = spawn("k2pdfopt", settings);

  child.stdout.on("data", data => {
    // ...
    ws.send(percentageDone); // <--- connection is broken before this is called
  });
};
```

I have tried to make the transformPDF function a promise and then awaiting it. I have also tried adding an optional `detached` option to the spawn process. I'm not really sure why it's closing since I've also successfully replaced the command `k2pdfopt` with something like a lengthy `find`, and that worked just fine (although it did batch all of the data in the stdout before calling `ws.send`).

Any help or insight on why it's closing is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when I was creating a child process, it was resetting the Visual Studio Code live-server extension that I had running the index.html. That explains why I was also getting a status code of 1001, which I found out most likely means the client refreshed.

I fixed the issue by simply installing the node package live-server and running my index.html from a different terminal.